# how to collect response for azure mobile service call from windows phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, azure-mobile-services

i am using azure mobile service in my windows phone application, while inserting data in the user table i use the below service call.

```
private async void SaveUser()
{
   try
   {
     await UserTable.InsertAsync(UserObject);
   }
   catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
   {

   }
}
```

in case of success how to collect the response of the above service call

Comment: Try to avoid async void methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @AntonSizikov: can u plz suggest a better way to write this function.

Comment: use Task<> return types, for void return types - simply return Task.

Answer (score 1):

In case of success the object you passed to the `InsertAsync` call will have been modified. See an example in the code below:

```
private async Task SaveUser()
{
    try
    {
        var userObject = new UserObject { Name = "Scooby Doo", Age = 11 };
        await UserTable.InsertAsync(userObject);
        var objId = userObject.Id;
        Trace("The id of the object is {0}", objId);
    }
    catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
    {
    }
}

public class UserObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to collect the response from the service call.

Comment: Do you want to see the actual HTTP response?

Comment: @carlosfigueira what's the way to get the HTTP response code?

Comment: On successful inserts, the response code is 201, unless you changed your insert script. On failure, you can find the response object in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

InsertAsync should return you a type of Task which you can do all sorts of magic with (like the following to check to see if the actual call resulted in a Fault).

```
var serviceCall = UserTable.InsertAsync(userObject);

await serviceCall;

if(serviceCall.IsFaulted)
{
success = false;
}
```